# CURL doesn't post data PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am doing a curl in PHP to post data on site and echo the result but it doesn't post data
here is my code:

```
<?php
$imei = "imei=XXXXXXXXX";

//set POST variables
$url = 'http://XXX.com/XXX.php';


//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $imei);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.XXX.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, fopen('php://output', 'w+'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);



//close connection
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
echo $imei;

?>
```

when i echo $imei, it shows up the full string but data isn't passed :S

Please help, what's wrong with code??

Thanks in advance

Update: In the orgignal html of the website it's name="imei" not id="imei"

Comment: You should have to echo the string `$result`

Comment: That's not my probelm, even if I echo the result it doesn't show Data posted it says invalid imdi because it hasn't been passed

Comment: What do you expect from echo $imei; ? It is "imei=XXXXXXXXX"

Comment: I'm echoing it to make sure that it's set correctly

Comment: How do you know it's not passed? Make a script on your server with `<?php print_r($_POST); ?>` and do a request to that script url to check if POST data is passed or not. Are you sure the url you request is correct? I see no *www.* there and they might redirect you to the url with *www.* and POST data is lost on redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't set the option `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`. cURL does not return the response if you don't set this option to `true`.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

I also suggest changing your POST data to an array instead of a string. The cURL option accepts an array and it automatically builds and encodes the string from that. if you build it yourself, you have to encode it as well.

```
$imei = array('imei' => 'XXXXXXXXX');
```

Edit: based on your debug data, I think your resource requires a GET request not post.
You should also set a user-agent, because the site may reject requests without one:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)');
```

From the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

> **CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER**
>   TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.

Comment: still having the same problem :S
\

Comment: What does `var_dump($result);` show? Also check your error log

Comment: $result: shows the webpage with error that the imei hasn't been passed

Comment: I think you need a `GET` request not `POST`, so remove the curl post options, and set your URL to `http://XXX.com/XXX.php?imei=xxxxx`.

Comment: Also, in your debug data comment, the site IP is present, you should remove that unless you want to name the site.

Comment: same probelm....but in debug shows that the full url with variable  
what do you think is the problem???
vy the way I'm trying on more than a server

Comment: See my edit, you need to do a GET request and set a user-agent string.

Comment: It was the user agent
Thank you very much :D :D :D :D :D